# What is the best free portable 3d/2d engine?

Tags: c++, game-engine

i like to make very simple 3d/2d game for pc/mac/linux
what is the best free 3d/2d engine for this ?
i have no experience in game programming so i guess it have to be easy to learn 
please in c++
thanks

Comment: Perhaps this is better as community wiki as really it's quite subjective?

Comment: There's no "best". lots of variables, ranging from from your skill level, to your intentions (hobby vs commercial?) to your game's inherent needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While 'best' can very much depend on your situation, one I have used in the past to great success is [OGRE 3D](http://www.ogre3d.org).

It's cross-platform, very nicely written (C++), and runs well. However the one thing that set it apart for me was the great community - you can always get help no matter how simple your question, and there are plenty of guides/tutorials around on their forum/wiki. The documentation is also very good.

It's well worth checking out.

Hrmm, upon reading that it almost sounds like I have a vested interest - I don't! I just really like it from past experience!

Comment: nitpick: Ogre 3D isn't really a GAME engine. It only does graphics (without other frameworks/plugins).

Comment: True, although I interpreted the request for a '2d/3d engine' in such a way that Ogre would be a valid response. Also, there have been full game engines built on it too, of course. Still, you raise a good point!

Comment: OGRE is purely a graphics rendering engine, but this design is purposeful as it allows other components to be "plugged in".  It doesn't fix you to a certain physics/sound engine so there's much more freedom in using it.  I'd definitely recommend it though - it's used in some top selling games (Ankh)

Answer (score 6):

Try searching [DevMaster's Game and Graphics Engines Database](http://www.devmaster.net/engines/) for 3D engines. This question has also been asked and answered [MANY](http://www.devmaster.net/forums/showthread.php?t=13873&highlight=2d+engine) [MANY](http://www.devmaster.net/forums/showthread.php?t=13627&highlight=C+game+engine) times in their [forums](http://www.devmaster.net/forums/).

[C4 Engine](http://www.terathon.com/c4engine/index.php), [irrLicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) and [Torque](http://www.garagegames.com/) are often recommended for 3D in C++, but it really depends on your individual requirements or if you really need an engine at all.

Comment: I don't recommend the database, but do recommend their forums. Signal-to-noise ratio is very good there.

Comment: @alphadogg Yes, the forums are very good. Unfortunately, I've been spending more time here than there. -monjardin

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/). It's simple, lightweight but fast and powerful. It's not as featureful as Ogre3D, but I've found it more simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

[Panda3D](http://panda3d.org/) is quite easy:

1. You can use it with C++ (or Python.)
2. It is well documented and offers many good samples.

It's mostly 3d oriented, so be aware although any 3d engine will involve a learning curve, Panda3D will have one of the shortest.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for more of a simple API rather than a full-blown game engine, you should try [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/).  That will give you a platform-independent way to render with OpenGL, handle input, do basic audio, etc.  It's especially handy if you're looking for a way to do a simple 2D game project.